# I can't identify the endl character \n in my if statement

Tags: c++, string, char

I am creating ASCII art for a game and my `fstream` is not receiving the `'\n'` (using `char`) in my if statement to delete from the stream. Seems simple, but I am puzzled at it right now..Any clue?

```
void pic_maker(ifstream &Pic_file, string P_Name, int x, int y, int t)
{
Pic_file.open(P_Name);
int margin = 0;
coordinate(x, y);
char pic_info;
Pic_File >> pic_info;

while (!Pic_File.eof())
{
    while (pic_info == '?')
    {
        Pic_File >> pic_info; //ADDS SPACES TO IMAGE BY REPLACING ?
        cout << " ";
    }
    if (pic_info == '0') //RETURNS TO NEW LINE
    {
        Pic_File >> pic_info;
        y++;
        coordinate(x, y);
    }
    if (pic_info == '\n') //MY PROBLEM! DOESN'T RECOGNIZE \n
    {
        Pic_File >> pic_info;
    }
    cout << pic_info;
    Pic_file >> pic_info;
}

Sleep(t);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIR the >> operator by default skips the newline character. If you want to read the whitespaces also, then you should add `noskipws` before reading the characters.

```
Pic_File >> std::noskipws;
```

Comment: Thanks! That saved many more issues I was trying to resolve and more!

Answer (score 0):

The formatted input operator skip leading whitespace. Clearing the format flag `std::ios_base::skipws` for the stream, e.g., using the `std::noskipws` manipulator, avoids this skipping of whitespace.

I would rather us unformatted input operations, e.g., one of the `std::istream::get()` members or `std::getline()`.

Comment: Thanks.. getline() might be more efficient. One more question. To simplify my function process I want to call a string by reference to the fstream function .open("blah") through my function name..void     pic_maker(ifstream &Pic_file, string P_Name, int x, int y, int t) how must I use Pic_file.open(P_Name) ?

Comment: @user3027652: `std::string`s are objects and not called. What is your question, though? Something I forgot to mention: do **not** use `eof()` to control you input loop! It does **not** work! Instead use the stream conversion to `bool` to test _after_ the input that it was successful.

Comment: If you are using a pre-C++11 library you need to get a C-string from the `std::string` object: `str.c_str()`

Comment: How do I use my P_Name in parameter within the function? I put Pic_file.open(P_Name); and got an error saying no matching function for call to 'std::base_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&) I edited the code to include this part

Comment: eof() worked for me. Should I include the #bool and discard the eof()?

Comment: @Dljcali: see my previous comment: pre-C++11 therebwas no `open()` or constructor of `std::ifstream` taking a `std::string`. There are corresponding functions taking a `char const*`, however, i.e., you'd use `str.c_str()`.

Comment: Saved me about a million minutes of stress! haha. Weird that never existed before.. but works! Thanks you've been much help!

Comment: @Dljcali: when using `in.eof()` to control you loop you have two immediate problems: 1. the last item has a fair chance to be processed twice, and 2. if the stream gors bad you get an infinite loop. There are more elaborate answers in Stackoverflow on why not to use `in.eof()` to control a loop.